# How can I find a messages pfp on discord using js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

What method can I use to find out someones pfp on discord using a javascript bot.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Using `User#avatarURL` or `User#displayAvatarURL`

`<Message>.author.displayAvatarURL()`

View the guide [Here](https://discordjs.guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Please make your answer clearer in future.

In this case you are asking for either `User#avatarURL` for a profile picture and `User#displayavatarURL` for a profile picture including default discord profiles

you can use `<Message>.author.displayavatarURL()` or `<Message>.author.avatarURL()`

it can also be inserted as a format for a gif aswell
you can check the guide for formatting [Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ImageURLOptions) and for the guides for avatar URL, view it [Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=avatarURL)